# Начинаем писать под Android

Tags: android

Вопросы задаю, чтобы точнее написать ТЗ для проекта:

1. Насколько я знаю, Android работает с реляционной sqllite БД, и так же известно, что удалённо к sqllite никак не подключиться. Какие из известных способов существуют, чтобы приложение получало данные из интернета. Какие быстрее и практичнее?
2. Насколько я знаю, парсят инфу через WebView. По-умолчанию он кеширует данные? Юзеру не придётся два раза загружать ту же страницу возвращаясь назад и снова на неё заходя?
3. Когда целесобразно использовать RelativeLayout, как это повлияет на разношёрстность устройств и разрешений?
4. Проштудируйте, пожалуйста, данный лог для начинающего. Что означает каждая из ошибок?

> `error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'id' with value '1'). main.xml    /Kamchatka/res/layout   line 7  Android AAPT Problem`
>
> `[I18N] Hardcoded string "Button", should use @string resource main.xml    /Kamchatka/res/layout   line 30 Android Lint Problem`
>
> `Attribute android:inputType should not be used with <TextView>: Change element type to <EditText> ?   main.xml    /Kamchatka/res/layout   line 21 Android Lint Problem`
>
> `This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view    main.xml    /Kamchatka/res/layout   line 7  Android Lint Problem`
>
> `Use a layout_height of 0dip instead of wrap_content for better performance    main.xml    /Kamchatka/res/layout   line 9  Android Lint Problem`

Answer (score 5):

1) json, xml, просто текстовые данные через сокет.

2) можно конечно, но смысл это делать... нет, как студенческий проект пойдет, но для нормального проекта - нет.

3) все зависит от задачи.

4)

> error: Error: Integer types not
> allowed (at 'id' with value '1').
> main.xml /Kamchatka/res/layout line 7
> Android AAPT Problem

человеческим языком говорит, что id не может быть числом. обычно он выглядит так @+id/имя

> [I18N] Hardcoded string "Button",
> should use @string resource main.xml
> /Kamchatka/res/layout line 30 Android
> Lint Problem

Это Вам рекомендуют строки сразу выносить в файл strings.xml, что бы потом проще было в будущем делать локализации.

> Attribute android:inputType should not
> be used with <TextView>: Change
> element type to <EditText> ? main.xml
> /Kamchatka/res/layout line 21 Android
> Lint Problem

Опять, человеческим языком намекает, что у данного view нет нужного свойства и рекомендует использовать другое view, у которого это свойство есть (то есть, компилятор подозревает опечатку).

> This RelativeLayout layout or its
> LinearLayout parent is possibly
> useless; transfer the background
> attribute to the other view main.xml
> /Kamchatka/res/layout line 7 Android
> Lint Problem

говорит, что у вас лишний лайаут.

> Use a layout_height of 0dip instead of
> wrap_content for better performance
> main.xml /Kamchatka/res/layout line 9
> Android Lint Problem

почему нужно именно так делать - разрабы андроида думаю лучше знают свое детище.

С английским точно дружим?

Comment: Английский со словарём, просто сложно с php, переходить на Java и C# и эти огроменные SDK, с кучей дебагеров, компиляторов, логов, и прочей полезной мутотени.
2 вопрос там про КЕШ!)

Comment: И всё-таки какой вариант из 1п. самый быстрый и удобный?

Comment: пункт 1) все сильно зависит от задачи. Можно даже зипованый protobuf. должно быть достаточно быстро.
пункт 2) не используйте webview  для того, что бы получать и парсить данные. И никаких проблем с кешем.